# How to use selenium with chrome driver on Amazon Linux. error: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, selenium, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use selenium-webdriver on Linux in my Rails project. It works fine locally on my mac, but it doesn't on remote server, Amazon Linux.

Here is the machine info

```
$ uname --all
Linux ip-172-31-21-116 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 17 22:45:04 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And this is the error I've got.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397932 (282ed7cf89cf0053b6542e0d0f039d4123bbb6ad),platform=Linux 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)
```

I installed the chromedriver and put `/usr/local/bin`

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5952376 Jun  4 12:54 chromedriver
```

This is what I installed
    http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.22/chromedriver_linux64.zip

Please help me so that I can use Selenium on my Linux. Thanks

Comment: have you tried using this gem? https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto Thanks for your comment. I tried that gem, but it failed with the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally not use Selenium in AWS. I tried http://phantomjs.org that is a similar concept but without the requirement of a browser
Phantom has a Full web stack plus no browser required

The only thing is that may take quite a while to compile, but give it a try, and you will have no more headaches with Selenium. 
I find Selenium good but to test locally, where you can see the browser opening and filling forms. But on the server I would use something different, that runs silently with minimun requirements and can be run from command-line without a browser.

Comment: your comment didn't solve the problem above, but it helped me. I tried PhantomJS. it works fine, although sometimes I got an error "PhantomJS has crashed." I will work on that.

Comment: I found that sometimes PhantomJS is not reliable with complex Forms that use Collections since this requires front-end javascript, other than that works really good to test stuff, at least for me :)

Answer (score 0):

What you've installed is just the Chrome WebDriver binding.
You will also need to install [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) (and [XServer](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/w-exTpGGah8))

Comment: @the_noob I already installed them. I'm now trying PhantomJS, so I will check it again if they are installed properly later.